# -= operator in C#

Tags: c#, operators

Help, I just cannot get my head around this.

```
int value = 0;
int i = 5;

value -= i;
Console.WriteLine("Test5 = " + value.ToString());

value -= i - 2;
Console.WriteLine("Test5 = " + value.ToString());
```

Im thinking the output would be:

```
Test5 = -5    // value = 0 - 5
Test5 = -2    // value = -5 --5 -2
```

Why is the correct answer :

```
Test5 = -5
Test5 = -8
```

Where is the -8 coming from????

Ty

Comment: Because 5 - 2 = 3 and -5 - 3 = -8. `i - 2` is evaluated first.

Comment: The reason is that `-=` is Right Associative

Answer (score 6):

Simple mathematics.

```
int value = 0;
int i = 5;

value -= i;
Console.WriteLine("Test5 = " + value.ToString());
```

After the above code, we have the following values:

`value` = -5

`i` = 5

Next, you do this:

```
value -= i - 2;
Console.WriteLine("Test5 = " + value.ToString());
```

Which can be rewritten as (note the brackets around everything that came after the `-=`):

```
value = value - (i - 2);
```

`i` = 5, so `i - 2` = 3.

`-5 - 3` = `-8`.

The brackets, obviously, don't really exist. It's just that the right side of the `-=` (or `+=`, `*=`, `/=`, `^=`, etc.) is evaluated to a single number first.

Comment: Does the bracket applies to all the different operators? (*=.+= etc...)

Comment: Just like in math, brackets (actually parentheses) can be used to manipulate the order of operations within any expression.

Comment: Yes, adding brackets means that what ever is inside the bracket will be evaluated before that result is applied outside the bracket.